# Scroll to top in a recycler view

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-recyclerview

Under certain conditions, I want to set a particular item in my navigation drawer (built with [RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)) as selected, through my script. So I am using code below

```
recyclerView.findViewHolderForPosition(1).itemView.performClick();
```

The problem is, when the intended item is not in the view port (say someone scrolled down to the bottom of the Nav drawer), it gives `NullPointerException` (I guess that is the expected behavior, as that item is recycled).

Can anyone please suggest what can I do? One way I was thinking is to scroll to the top automatically before calling above function, but I'm not sure if that is possible. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: in your model you have a kind of boolean variable indicating if an item is selected or not, so set it on and call `notifyItemChanged(int position)` or `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to set selected item of RecycleView. You can change your `RecyclerView.Adapter` with this way:

```
class YourModel{
   public boolean isSelected;
}


 public class CustomRecycleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

   List<YourModel> listData;

   // your View Holder
   class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public View rootLayout; // your root item layout
        public ContentViewHolder(View itemView) {
        // get root layout
        }
   } 

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder)holder;
        if(listData.get(position).isSelected{
           // set selected like this:
           viewHolder.rootLayout.setSelected(true);
        }else{
           viewHolder.rootLayout.setSelected(false);
        }
   }

  public void setSelected(int position, boolean isSelected){
    listData.get(position).isSelected =  isSelected;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
}
```

Finally, use this code in your activity:

```
CustomRecycleAdapter recycleAdapter; // init it
recycleAdapter.setSelected(0, true);
```

Comment: Thanks .. I tried this way, but the issue is setSelected() method is not accessible from my activity. Here recycleAdapter is a RecyclerView.Adapter object, right?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that `findViewHolderForPosition` returns null if the view holder is not available (it's offscreen - recycled). In that case, you can simply do nothing. The view will show the new appearance when it is scrolled into view by the user and your bind is called at that point (until then, visual appearance of the item does not matter...)

Comment: Sorry, I am not clear. If I don't call that performClick, the drawer item appearance will not changed (normally the text is black, it turns to blue if anyone click on any item, to denote the active item).